# Integrating Discovery Miles Into Website

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, payment-gateway

My website, written in EE2 is using expresso-store as the shopping cart. I am integrating PayU  payment gateway via the Enterprise API. Would it be possible to use Discovery Miles with this? How would I integrate Discovery Miles here or how would I go about doing this? The customer is allowed to pay with their discovery miles or credit card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PayU support payment by Discovery Card ([and it looks like they do](https://www.payu.co.za/business/supported-payment-methods/)) then you just need to implement a payment gateway for PayU and PayU will automatically provide that as a payment option presented to customers.

Discovery Miles is the currency earned when customer makes a payment with their Discovery Card and that again is handled automatically by the issuer: DiscoveryCard.